# Reading excel files in pyspark with 3rd row as header

Tags: excel, pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to read read excel files as spark dataframe with 3rd row as a header.The synatax to read excel files as spark dataframe  with 1st row as header is :

```
s_df  = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
                           .option("header", "true") \
                           .option("inferSchema", "true") \
                           .load(path + 'Sales.xlsx')
```

and the equivalent syntax to read as pandas dataframe with 3rd row as header is :

```
p_df = pd.read_excel(path + 'Sales.xlsx',header=3)
```

I want to do the same thing in pyspark that is to read excel files as  spark dataframe with 3rd row as header.

Comment: Can you read it with pandas and convert to spark dataframe? Excel files are typically not large and pandas should be able to handle

Comment: yes, I can do that but is there any way to read the file directly as spark dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dataAddress option to specify the cell/row where the data is located . As you need to skip two rows, your data (including header) starts from row A3.

```
s_df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
           .option("header", "true") \
           .option("inferSchema","true") \
           .option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!A3") \
           .load("yourfilepath")
```

Also, note that if your first two rows are empty, then dataAddress does not have to specified. The leading null rows will be skipped by default.

Check the documentation [here](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/blob/main/README.md)